# Using an interface as a type

Tags: java

I've been looking through some production code, and I'm a little confused on the concept of using an interface as a type (object)

I saw this explanation http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html

Here's the code below:

```
public Object findLargest(Object object1, Object object2) {
   Relatable obj1 = (Relatable)object1;
   Relatable obj2 = (Relatable)object2;
   if ( (obj1).isLargerThan(obj2) > 0)
      return object1;
   else 
      return object2;
}
```

Where `Relatable` is an interface, I don't understand where it gets the logic for the `isLargerThan(obj2)` function call.

Can somebody make this clear for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logic comes from the class which implements the interface. This is exactly the reason why you cannot directly instantiate an interface, because the interface itself doesn't contain any implementation. The language ensures that the objects passed to your method are of a concrete class that implements the methods in the interface.

Comment: Do you know what happens if the object doesn't implement the interface?

Comment: @Albinoswordfish there would be a ClassCastException at (Relatable)object1;

Comment: It throws an exception:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

You can use the `instanceof` operator to check for a valid cast before the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

It's assumed that the objects are actually of types that implement the interface; otherwise, you'd get a `ClassCastException` when casting.

Comment: It would throw a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 2):

While the compile time type of `obj1` is `Relatable`, the runtime type is some concrete class that implements `Relatable`. The code that actually gets called is defined by that runtime type. This is known as [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).